# Bootstrap Tour - How do I return back from destination page?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with Bootstrap Tour and I have found myself stuck navigating pages.

In my tour, step four takes users from index.cshtml to page.cshtml which works fine, however the tour box does not open in page.cshtml so I cannot navigate back from the destination page.

In the Bootstrap tour demo at bootstraptour.com I cannot identify the javascript to open the tour popup in page.cshtml or handle the return back to index.cshtml.  There is just a div with a class called container and the dependency links in the Bootstraptour demo page.html.

I have tried different options with no joy.  So, can anyone please help me open a pop up in page.cshtml and use it to navigate back to the original index.cshtml?  Thanks.

Here is what I have:

**index.cshtml**

```
    @{    
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <!-- Le Bootstrap Styles -->
       <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Bootstrap Tour -->
       <link href="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

<body>

</br>
     </br>

          <p class="step-handle" id="step-welcome"> step welcome </p></br>
          <p class="step-handle" id="step-one"> step 1</p></br>
          <p class="step-handle" id="step-two"> step 2 </p></br>
          <p class="step-handle" id="step-three"> step 3 </p></br>
          <p class="step-handle" id="step-four"> step 4</p></br>
          <p class="step-handle" id="step-five"> step 5 </p></br> <!-- DOES STEP FIVE GO IN page.cshtml? -->
          <p class="step-handle" id="step-six"> step 6</p></br>

<hr />

<button id="pause-tour">Pause Tour</button>
<hr />
<button id="resume-tour">Resume Tour</button>


    </body>
</html>
      <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var tour = new Tour({
    afterSetState: function(key, value) {
                console.log(key, value, tour.getState(), tour.getStep());
            }
});

tour.addSteps([
        {
        element: "#welcome", 
        title: "WELCOME", 
        content: "Welcome to the bootstrap tour" 
    },
    {
        element: "#step-one", // string (jQuery selector) - html element next to which the step popover should be shown
        title: "Step One Title", // string - title of the popover
        content: "Step One Content" // string - content of the popover
    },
    {
        element: "#step-two",
        title: "Step Two Title",
        content: "Step Two Content"
    },
    {
        element: "#step-three",
        title: "Step Three Title",
        content: "Step Three Content"
    },
    {
       path: "/page.cshtml",
       element: "#step-four",
        title: "Step four Title",
        content: "Step four Content"
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        title: "Step five Title",
        content: "Step five Content"
    },
    {
        element: "#step-six",
        title: "Step six Title",
        content: "Step six Content"
    }
]);

tour.restart();

$("#pause-tour").on("click", function() {

    tour.end();

});


$("#resume-tour").on("click", function() {

    tour.start(true);

});
</script>
```

**page.cshtml**

```
    @{

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>


        <!-- Le Bootstrap Styles -->
       <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Bootstrap Tour -->
       <link href="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>


    <body>


        <div class="container">
          <h1>This is just a test.</h1>
          <p>Nothing to see here. Move on!</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
      <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of issues:

1. The element you specify for the step four (`#step-four`) is not found in the markup for `page.cshtml`
2. Step five does not have an `element` defined, I believe one is required unless you set the `orphan` option to `true`
3. You must include all your tour code in `page.cshtml` too, if you check the source of the demo in `page.html` the last referenced script `index.js` contains the tour instance.

Finally, I'm not sure if this would make any difference but I think your calls to `tour.restart();` and  `tour.start(true);` should swap places

Comment: Hi koala_dev, thanks for the help. My page.cshtml attempts had #step-four mark up and the step five element defined (that must have got dropped off cutting and pasting into this post). As I could not include all the different page.cshtml variations I had tried, I left a template page.cshtml to see if someone would add the return step to show me how to get back to index.cshtml. I had the code in both pages too initially and the js nearly worked flicking between pages. I 'did miss' the referenced js in the demo though which threw me, so 'thanks' for that. Anyway, I got there (see above) Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem as like the Danib facing ,,, should you help me @koala_dev

Answer (score 1):

After taking another look at how to navigate pages in the tour I got back to where I was yesterday: The tour changes from index.cshtml to page.cshtml and back, but it happens in one click - page.cshtml just flashes open.  The tour step popup does not open in page.cshtml and we do not stay on that page.

So, I thought that I would add another step to page.cshtml (step five and step six) and BINGO!

Thanks to kuala_dev for the pointer.  The working code is below:

**INDEX.CSHTML**

```
@{    
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <!-- Le Bootstrap Styles -->
       <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Bootstrap Tour -->
       <link href="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

<body>

</br>
     </br>

          <p class="step-handle" id="step-welcome"> step welcome </p></br>
          <p class="step-handle" id="step-one"> step 1</p></br>
          <p class="step-handle" id="step-two"> step 2 </p></br>
          <p class="step-handle" id="step-three"> step 3 </p></br>
          <p class="step-handle" id="step-four"> step 4</p></br>

          <p class="step-handle" id="step-seven"> step 7</p></br>

<hr />

<button id="pause-tour">Pause Tour</button>
<hr />
<button id="resume-tour">Resume Tour</button>


    </body>
</html>
      <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var tour = new Tour({
    afterSetState: function(key, value) {
                console.log(key, value, tour.getState(), tour.getStep());
            }
});

tour.addSteps([
        {
        element: "#welcome", 
        title: "WELCOME", 
        content: "Welcome to the bootstrap tour" 
    },
    {
        element: "#step-one", 
        title: "Step One Title", 
        content: "Step One Content" 
    },
    {
        element: "#step-two",
        title: "Step Two Title",
        content: "Step Two Content"
    },
    {
       element: "#step-three",
        title: "Step three Title",
        content: "Step three Content"
    },
    {
        path: "/page.cshtml",
        element: "#step-four",
        title: "Step four Title",
        content: "Step four Content"
    },
        {
        element: "#step-five",
        title: "Step five Title",
        content: "Step five Content"
    },
    {
        path: "/index.cshtml",
        element: "#step-six",
        title: "Step six Title",
        content: "Step six Content"
    },
    {
        element: "#step-seven",
        title: "Step seven Title",
        content: "Step seven Content"
    }
]);

tour.restart();

$("#pause-tour").on("click", function() {

    tour.end();

});


$("#resume-tour").on("click", function() {

    tour.start(true);

});
</script>
```

**PAGE.CSHTML**

```
@{

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>


        <!-- Le Bootstrap Styles -->
       <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Bootstrap Tour -->
       <link href="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>


    <body>


           <hr>

<h2 class="step-handle" id="step-five" style="float: left">We're Big Show Offs</h2>

          <hr>

<h2 class="step-handle" id="step-six" style="float: left">We're Big Show Offs</h2>

    </body>
</html>
      <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var tour = new Tour({
    afterSetState: function(key, value) {
                console.log(key, value, tour.getState(), tour.getStep());
            }
});

tour.addSteps([
        {
        element: "#welcome", 
        title: "WELCOME", 
        content: "Welcome to the bootstrap tour" 
    },
    {
        element: "#step-one", 
        title: "Step One Title", 
        content: "Step One Content" 
    },
    {
        element: "#step-two",
        title: "Step Two Title",
        content: "Step Two Content"
    },
    {
       element: "#step-three",
        title: "Step three Title",
        content: "Step three Content"
    },
    {
        path: "/page.cshtml",
        element: "#step-four",
        title: "Step four Title",
        content: "Step four Content"
    },
        {
        element: "#step-five",
        title: "Step five Title",
        content: "Step five Content"
    },
    {
        path: "/index.cshtml",
        element: "#step-six",
        title: "Step six Title",
        content: "Step six Content"
    },
    {
        element: "#step-seven",
        title: "Step seven Title",
        content: "Step seven Content"
    }
]);

tour.restart();

$("#pause-tour").on("click", function() {

    tour.end();

});


$("#resume-tour").on("click", function() {

    tour.start(true);

});
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to add an extra step, it probably wasn't working correctly because you're calling `tour.restart()` instead of `tour.start()`

Comment: Hey, thanks again koala_dev, you were right I should have been using tour.start() - the tour works with just one step now.  I really appreciate your support.

Comment: Gald to help, wouldn't you say the answer I posted was correct then? I did note there may have been something off with the call to `restart()`

Comment: Yeh, I agree. When I last logged on I had a quick look for a link to mark you right or give you some kudos, but I didn't spot that clicking the tick would do it. Done now. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm having issues with multi page tours too.  I notice the above code uses restart instead of start.  Is this correct in the light of @koala_dev 's comment?